# Anyone working with Stretch Inc's S6 or S7 based chipset

Tags: embedded, h.264, video-encoding, stretch, surveillance

This is a long shot, but anyway ... I am developing a video DSP system based on the Stretch S6/S7 chipset and tools.  It is frequently used in the video surveillance market.  I would like to know if there are any other developers on StackOverflow who are working with Stretch's reference design platforms.  I would like to know if there is any kind of user forum available to exchange ideas and questions about this product line

Answer (score 2):

And looking into linux kernel source tree:

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/sound/soc/s6000/s6105-ipcam.c?v=2.6.31

http://tomoyo.sourceforge.jp/cgi-bin/lxr/source/arch/xtensa/platforms/s6105/device.c?a=m68k

u can identify the email of the source file and perhaps the relevant experienced person?